# concatinating two DataFrames without NaN in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have two dataframes,

```
df_temp,
       Age  Name    city
   0    1   Pechi   checnnai
   1    2   Sri     pune

df_po

        po
   0    er
   1    ty
```

I tried pd.concat([df_temp,df_po])

```
 df_temp=pd.concat([df_temp,df_po],ignore_index=True)
```

I am getting

```
        Age Name    city        po
   0    1.0 Pechi   checnnai    NaN
   1    2.0 Sri     pune        NaN
   2    NaN NaN     NaN         er
   3    NaN NaN     NaN         ty
```

but my desired output is,

```
        Age Name    city        po
   0    1.0 Pechi   checnnai    er
   1    2.0 Sri     pune        ty
```

Comment: Check the link , already have detail and answer there. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need `axis=1` for `columns` concatenate , because default is `axis=0` (`index` concatenate) in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df_temp=pd.concat([df_temp,df_po],axis=1)
print (df_temp)
   Age   Name      city  po
0    1  Pechi  checnnai  er
1    2    Sri      pune  ty
```

Alternative solution with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df_temp=df_temp.join(df_po)
print (df_temp)
   Age   Name      city  po
0    1  Pechi  checnnai  er
1    2    Sri      pune  ty
```

Comment: can you check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583113/comparing-two-dataframe-columns-to-check-if-they-have-same-value-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You should use: **ignore_index=True**  for sure

I also **recommend** that reset both data frames before concat command

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

Good Luck